# Getting Attribute Error using is.integer() on user input for multiplication table

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I've been trying to run through a few practice exercises with Python. I am trying to create a multiplication table where the user can pick a number and how many different multiples they wish to see. I am running into an AttributeError when the user tries to input how many multiples they wish to see and I was wondering if there was any way to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
def multiple_generator(multiple, number):

    if multiple.is_integer() or multiple > 0:
        for i in range(1, multiple + 1):
            print(f" {number} x {multiple} = {number * multiple}")
    else:
        print("Please input a positive integer numb nuts")

try:
    a = input("What number you want to multiply? ")
    b = input("How many multiples you want to see? ")
    multiple_generator(int(b), a)

except ValueError:
    print("Please input a positive integer ")
```

Comment: You forgot to cast `a` to `int`.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, whoops.

Comment: No I totally didn't even notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
def multiple_generator(multiple, number):

    if multiple > 0:
        for i in range(1, multiple + 1):
            print(f" {number} x {i} = {i * multiple}")
    else:
        print("Please input a positive integer numb nuts")

try:
    a = input("What number you want to multiply? ")
    b = input("How many multiples you want to see? ")
    multiple_generator(int(b), int(a))

except ValueError:
    print("Please input a positive integer ")
```

The reason your code didn't work because you forgot to cast `a` to an integer as well. Also `is_integer` is not needed since `b` is already casted to an integer type.

Comment: You should explain where OP went wrong, not just fix their code for them.

Comment: @blorgon Just explained

Comment: Your code doesn't multiply with each number from 1 to ```multiple```. It just multiplies ```number * multiple``` ```multiple``` number of times. You need to multiply by ```i```

Comment: @Sujay Yeah it's not so clear what the OP wants, anyways edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/is_integer.html):

> Returns True if the float instance is finite with integral value, and False otherwise.

When you are converting `b` to an integer and passing it, it is getting assigned to `multiple`. But, `is_integer()` method only works for floats. So you get an error.

You can simply do:

```
def multiple_generator(multiple, number):

    if float(multiple).is_integer() or multiple > 0:
        for i in range(1, multiple + 1):
            print(f" {number} x {i} = {i * multiple}")
    else:
        print("Please input a positive integer numb nuts")
```

But since `b` is already an integer, you can just check if `multiple > 0`

```
def multiple_generator(multiple, number):

    if multiple > 0:
        for i in range(1, multiple + 1):
            print(f" {number} x {i} = {i * multiple}")
    else:
        print("Please input a positive integer numb nuts")
```

---

Also, you are printing multiples of a number. But `input` returns a string. When you multiply string with an integer, it creates `n` copies of itself.

While passing the argument `a`, convert it to an integer.

Also, you need to multiply with `i` instead of `multiple`:

```
def multiple_generator(multiple, number):

    if multiple > 0:
        for i in range(1, multiple + 1):
            print(f" {number} x {i} = {number * i}") #=== Multiply by i
    else:
        print("Please input a positive integer numb nuts")

try:
    a = input("What number you want to multiply? ")
    b = input("How many multiples you want to see? ")

    multiple_generator(int(b), int(a)) #=== pass as An integer
```

Output:

```
What number you want to multiply? 2
How many multiples you want to see? 2
 2 x 1 = 2
 2 x 2 = 4
```